# is it possible to have conditional default scope in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, default-scope

I am on rails 3.2.21, ruby version is 2.0

My requirement is to have role based conditional default scope for a particular model. eg

consider role variable as an attribute of logged in user

```
if role == 'xyz'
  default_scope where(is_active: false)
elsif role == 'abc'
   default_scope where(is_active: true)
end
```

Comment: role is class variable or what ?

Comment: consider role as an attribute of logged in user

Comment: It seems like very bad pattern. What about gems such as CanCan?

Comment: Use a scope instead of it and pass a role parameter to it.

Comment: Ruby on Rails reached its end of life-cycle with the release of [Rails 5.0](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2016/6/30/Rails-5-0-final/) on June 30th, 2016. Updating to a maintained version (4.2.x or 5.0.x at the moment) is highly recommended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is impossible in programming.

Using `default_scope` is a bad idea in general (lots of articles are written on the topic).

If you insist on using current user's atribute you can pass it as an argument to scope:

```
scope :based_on_role, lambda { |role|
  if role == 'xyz'
    where(is_active: false)
  elsif role == 'abc'
    where(is_active: true)
  end
}
```

And then use it as follows:

```
Model.based_on_role(current_user.role)
```

Sidenote: Rails 3.2.x - seriously?...

Comment: Consider using `case role` over messy `if`s spaghetty. BTW, you have a typo in `elsif`.

Comment: @mudasobwa yep, thought about `case role`, but just copied what author had in OP.

Comment: Also, dynamically evaluated `lambda` differs from static implementation by OP.

Comment: decided to use scope as Andrey suggested.
yes on Rails 3.2.x, it is a legacy application, cost of migrating to newer version of Rails is high, but it is in pipeline.

Comment: @srikant please make sure to check the checkmark on the left near the answer if it answers your question

Comment: Plus one for 'Nothing is impossible in programming.' I tell my clients this all the time.

Answer (score 1):

```
default_scope where(
  case role
  when 'xyz' then { is_active: false }
  when 'abc' then { is_active: true }
  else '1 = 1'
  end
)
```

Also, please read the answer by Andrey Deineko, specifically the part about default scopes usage.

Comment: I think it will just throw `undefined variable or method 'role' for Model`

Comment: Once again, as I have said in the comment to your answer, there is a significant difference between static and dynamic clauses. This one is static, it’s evaluated in model’s context once.